# Уменьшение слово на 1 букву

Tags: c++

Нужно удалять одну букву слева и выводить полученный результат до тех пор, пока не останется одна буква. Как это можно исправить?

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s;
    cout << "Введите слово: ";
    getline(cin, s);
    int count = strlen(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; --s)
        cout << s;
    system("Pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Это можно сделать несколькими способами - смотрите функции, которые есть у класса string в MSDN, в частности substr() или replace() . Делать Ваше учебное задание здесь не будут.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Упсс :D

Comment: Я и не прошу :) Мне нужны лишь подсказки, которые помогут решить задачу ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char word[100];
    cout << "Enter word." << endl;
    cin.getline(word, 100);
    cout << "- - -" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; word[j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
            cout << word[j];
        } cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот как я предлагаю:

```
int main() {
    string s;
    cout << "Введите слово: ";
    getline(cin, s);

    while(s != "")  //пока не останется пустая строка
    {
        cout << s << endl;  //выводим строку
        s.pop_back();   //выкидываем последний символ
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно удалить символ из начала массива и так до конца, но в этом нет необходимости.
Вы можете использовать указатель на смещение в string и просто выводить последующие буквы из массива.

Вот пример, в нем я использую смещение относительно указателя на первый символ строки

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text;
    cout << "Please, write word: " << endl;
    getline(cin, text);
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        cout << text[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```